# Angular.js: Alter scope within a service

Tags: angularjs

I'm very new to AngularJS and wrote a service that's supposed to handle internationalization. I would like to have it handle the $scope directly instead of having to write some logic in each controller.

```
myServices.factory('i18n', ['$resource',

    function($resource){

        var lang = "en";
        var translations = {};

        var useLang = function(lang){

            return $resource('i18n/' + lang + '.json', {}, {
                        query: { method:'GET', isArray:false} }).query();
        }

        return {
            'useLang'       : useLang,
            translations    : useLang(lang),
        }
```

I would like to make the current controller's scope to be accessible directly in the service. Is that possible?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Abstracting logic out to services and then injecting them into your controllers makes loads of sense. Your controller should handle its own scope as it is bound to the template. Any logic or processing of scope data should be passed into your service and then relayed on to the template by your controller. Can you give an example of what you want your service to do with the $scope?